# Applications of Lax Milgram theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces

I'm now studying the Lax Milgram theorem and I want to get deep in that topic. What things do you recommend me to study? About generalizations, variational inequalities... 
And I also want to study applications of that theorem, especially in weak formulations, do you recommend me an interesting or new model or equation to study applying the theorem? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are interested in this theorem, maybe you are interested in the papers of Ramaswamy, *The Lax-Milgram theorem for Banach spaces, I* Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. Volume 56, Number 10 (1980), and respectively, Volume 57, Number 1 (1981). Currently you can read these from Project Euclid. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The theorem of Zarantonello goes just like the one for Lax-Milgram. It needs strongly monotone operators, but can handle nonlinear equations.

Also I find it useful to know for which PDEs *von Neumann boundary conditions* give unique solutions and not.